# SQL Server 2012 Express, Connection error 26, Local connection

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012-express

I am working locally on new laptop (windows 8 x64) with SQL Express 2012 SP1 x64, and I get the following connection error:

> *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.*
>
> *The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)*

Kindly notice that service `sqlserver` is running and that shared memory, TCP/IP, Named Pipes are all enabled.

**Sometimes connection is successful but only for a while.**

Usually I get the connection error.

Any ideas how to resolve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check if the database server folders are full. The problem could be something else, but this is the first thing I would check if I am able to connect sporadically.

Answer (score 1):

Check in Windows Services, sometimes the instance of SQL Server is stopped after some updates either in Visual Studio or SQL Server. I think you mean, sometimes IT IS NOT connecting, but after some seconds it does work. Am I correct?

Comment: This was my problem when a computer that had been running for hours couldn't connect to SQL Server express.  It happened very often.  I never had it die when already working though.

Answer (score 1):

I've renamed my computer, sql Express was looking for the database server on the wrong path. Renaming computer back or updating path would fix that.

That might not be your issue, but help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of SQL Express - can you connect to and use  - (localdb)/v11.0 ?

localdb is lighter weight comparing to sqlexpress and it is the recommended way for developers to put some data quickly in SQL. Also note that localdb does NOT run as a service but as an app, so it might be easier to connect to it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183379/is-there-a-difference-between-sql-server-express-2012-and-localdb) is a question discussing other differences.