# WPF Application with SQL Server Express database deployment in production environment

Tags: sql-server, wpf, entity-framework, localdb

I have a WPF application where I use Entity Framework for interacting with the database that is on SQL Server Express on my machine. I'm reasoning on small projects where data will not be huge and then I don't want to install SQL Server Express on client's machine for two reasons:

1. installation takes a long time
2. these projects must be executable on computers with low hardware specs (installation of SQL Server takes too much time)

I tried installing LocalDB on client machine, created default instance and started

The problems are two:

1. how to reconfigure `app.config` file making Entity Framework connecting to database? (in development environment connection string is SQL Server style)
2. where to put database files? (user's profile root?)

Am I following the correct way? I know only two way to do this, installing SQL Server Express or using LocalDB the may be a third way?

Comment: `LocalDB` ***IS*** SQL Server Express - just a special developer-oriented version of it that is **not** intended for production use

Comment: sorry @marc_s for the small delay in my delay to reply to you, i've seen a lot of SQL Server Express installed in production, we talk about small applications where the cost of SQL Server Standard is impossible to accept

Comment: Yes- the **full**, server-based SQL Server Express which by default is the `SQLEXPRESS` instance - that's fine (as long as your database stays below 10 GB) - but the SQL Server Express **LocalDB** edition is really designed for developer use only

Answer (score 1):

You can set up your app.config file as follows (just replace "C:\Database.mdf" with the full path to your database):

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="NameOfConnectionString" connectionString="data source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;attachdbfilename=C:\Database.mdf;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   </connectionStrings>
```

But with this you will end up having always the same static connection string.

Perhaps you want to store you database rather in some user folder.
This will get a sub folder of the users documents folder at runtime:

```
string folder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "MyAppsFolder");
```

If you want to deploy the local db to the users machine, you might want to create a installer project for this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351947/create-an-application-setup-in-visual-studio-2013)

The alternative would be to install some version of SQL-Server on the client machine.

If it is possible that one the client site you will have more than one concurrent user you will have no other choice.

**Difference between local db and SQL-Server express**

If you need more information on the usage scenarios of local db and SQL-Server express, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183379/is-there-a-difference-between-sql-server-express-2012-and-localdb) question and answers.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh510202(v=sql.120).aspx) MSDN Site has also a bunch of information on LocalDB.