# The underlying provider failed on Open after deleting database files and sqllocaldb

Tags: sql-server, uwp, localdb, desktop-bridge

I am investigating my experience of [the issue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13001441/delete-mdf-file-from-app-data-causes-exception-cannot-attach-the-file-as-databa)

When my Winforms XAF, Entity Framework Code First + Desktop Bridge application is installed via the Windows Store, it creates a database in the users directory.

If I delete the files then I will get an error when I try to re-run the application.

```
The underlying provider failed on Open
```

This is because I have not dropped the database properly.

As is explained in the linked issue.

I tried the fix of

```
sqllocaldb.exe stop MSSQLLocalDB
sqllocaldb.exe delete MSSQLLocalDB
```

But it did not fix the problem.
Moreover I cannot find the SQL Server instance to connect to ( via Management Studio 2017 ) In order to drop the database.

I have the following folders under c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server

[image: folders for sql server]

[Update]

I tried running

```
sqllocaldb.exe info mssqllocaldb
```

which gives Version 13.1.4001.0

to get an instance pipe name to use to connect via SQL Server Object Explorer
I was then able to create a new database of the same name, and then delete it.
However this did not solve my problem.

[Update]

The connection string is

```
"Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=mydatabase"
```

I have asked [a related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909226/why-cant-i-see-a-localdb-database-created-by-a-uwp-desktop-bridge-app-in-the)

I am now thinking that localdb is not supported for UWP

Comment: What does the connection string look like for the application?  It would help in understanding where to look and how to access the store.

Comment: Also [check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21563940/how-to-connect-to-localdb-in-visual-studio-server-explorer) depending on what version of local db you have you might be able to figure it out.

Comment: Thanks @JohnBabb I updated the question.

Comment: Kirsten, did you find an answer?  I have a scorched earth approach I use when LocalDB instances get funky, involving deleting the instance directories, and the registry keys that point to them.  If you still need help resolving this, I can give you the details.

Comment: Thanks @RichardII After reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42028186/sql-server-express-vs-express-localdb   I switched to SQLite

Answer (score 0):

With Management Studio 2017, if you run it as an admin, you should be able to connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB with a trusted connection.  This should bring up the service that will give you visibility to what databases are attached.  From there you should be able to drop/create... do what is needed to config and set the context of the database.

Comment: I am able to connect to (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB but the database is not listed when it is created via the UWP program.

Comment: Double check by refreshing the explorer window at the server level.

Comment: Thanks, that does not help.