# What database should I choose for prerequisites?

Tags: c#, sql-server, advanced-installer

I have a C# project that I want create a setup for. I use Advanced Installer.

I use SQL Server 2017 Express for creating instance of my database. Now when I want to choose "Prerequisites", I have 2 options:

1. SQL Server 2017 Express
2. SQL Server 2017 Express Local DB

What should I choose, and what's the difference?

Comment: You can see this link https://www.quora.com/Which-database-tool-should-I-use-for-a-standalone-Visual-Studio-C-application-on-desktop ,I hope to help you

Comment: I think you use `SQL Server Express local Db 2017`, because this version of Sql Server is very easy for install by users. Maybe you need to change your connection string.

Comment: @Mofid.Moghimi hi sir are you iranian ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183379/is-there-a-difference-between-sql-server-express-2012-and-localdb

Comment: @Buzzzzzzz I read this but it make me more confuse ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL Server Express LocalDB: This edition is mainly used as a development tool. It is a lighter version of Express that runs as a local app. It does support all the main programmability features of the other editions.

The big advantage of LocalDB for developers is that it allows them to create a local environment that is much easier to install and manage. Users can just start up an instance of LocalDB runtime as they need it and do not need to install a service.

For details, please check the [SQL Server Express LocalDB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-express-localdb?view=sql-server-2017) article.