# Can't connect local mdf database file

Tags: c#, sql-server, connection, database-connection, local-database

I build a simple CRUD app in C# and used server based database file (.mdf) in my Project. My connection string is like this:

```
public string connectionString { get; set; } = $"Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=\"{AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory}Passwords.mdf\";Integrated Security=True";
```

In my computer application works fine just I want, but after send to my friend, he got error that can't connect or find SQL database. Error text is:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
> establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
> was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
> SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL
> Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance
> Specified

So we download SQL server express 2019 for him (I use 2017 by the way) and after that, still he get the same error. I dont understand what is the problem. Any succession?

Comment: LocalDB and Express aren't the same. Installing Express won't fix the error. How did you "send" the application to your friend? As an installer?

Comment: @Larnu is right, they aren't the same thing.  Here's some leisure reading: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10183379/is-there-a-difference-between-sql-server-express-2012-and-localdb

Comment: Larnu, I sent it in winrar, exe file and mdf file together in a folder

Comment: Larnu, what should I do in this situation, how he connect the mdf file?

Comment: Search "how to deploy application with localdb"

Comment: See also [what's the issue with AttachDbFilename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11178720/whats-the-issue-with-attachdbfilename), you really shouldn't use it. Just `ATTACH` the database normally. This is true even with LocalDB